# Read-only file randomly

Tags: fsck, read-only

I use my Ubuntu PC as a Server to host a Minecraft Server and other stuff developed by me. I noticed frequent crashes of the Minecraft Server that made me look further into the error. When I opened any folder any file inside of it has Cut, Rename and Delete options disabled.

I tried running FSCK from the terminal. That found some errors and fixed it, upon rebooting it btw files were switched again in Read-Only after 10 minutes.

```
fsck
```

Initially, I was thinking at HDD problem, looked at SMART info, ran several Self-Test and scanned for bad blocks using the command above. But everything looks good and 0 Bad Blocks was found, scan lasted several hours.

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda2

Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Also lately, not sure if it can help with troubleshooting, i've been getting pop up saying "File System Error"

I'm not sure what to do next.

EDIT:
I run FSCK once again. As soon I start the device up everything is accessible, after some minutes, a message pop-up saying: "System program problem". I can't screenshot it, but this is a similiar photo of the error, taken from google. After I close the pop-up everything gets on read-only.
[Error Photo URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVij0.png)

I also have one other machine with another Linux distro, having a similar pop-up happening regularly. Can it be caused by Faulty USB Drive I used to install the OS?

You can find [Crash Report Files](https://mega.nz/folder/eUhXHKST#U5ofeRM7ISjKp_Drn1lPbg) here

Comment: It's probably a bad drive, irrespective of the tests.

Comment: I'd also check the rest of your hardware for issues; ie. even good components misbehave when fed faulty power (ie. check PSU), if RAM is faulty issues will show (check RAM), let alone *cap scan* for general motherboard issues (though these usually show by random freezes/halts of the system) etc

Comment: Thank's for the head up guys! I updated the thread with some new info, hope they can help finding the problem! @guiverc

Comment: It's extremely unlikely (*in my opinion*) to be related to a bad USB however I don't know your release. Modern releases validate the media and it would have shown, and if you were on an older release (that doesn't auto-validate itself) your own checks should have detected flaws; so I'd discount media (*only you can know if you execute proper security procedures though*). System Problem detected tells me nothing; unless you've explored the .crash file in `/var/crash/` (the filename itself tells you a load of detail; as I cannot see that directory though I cannot see anything).

Comment: Thank you! There are 3 files that i cannot open or share since i can't even access my USB Drive from that PC or use Browser. They are named: _usr_lib_systemd_systemd.0.crash; _usr_lib_udisks2_udisksd.0.crash; _usr_libexec_fwupd_fwupd.0.crash. Would like to add that now i can't even write any file on System @guiverc

Comment: I was able to extract the content of these crash reports, should be on the thread in a minute @guiverc